# Button's text not change on RecyclerView

Tags: android

I have a code for RecyclerView where I added 3 buttons one of them is Shortlist button. When I am clicking on button, success is coming from server on volley response. I need when I clicked on button then button's text should be changed and another's item will not be effected.

Below is my CardAdapter class where I extends RecyclerView.Adapter

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private static final String url ="http://192.168.2.110/xp/shortlist1.php";
private static final String url1 = "http://192.168.2.110/xp/express_intrest.php";
private static final String KEY_MATRI_ID_TO="matriID_to";
private static final String KEY_MATRI_ID_BY="matriID_by";

SessionManager session;
public String matri_id_to, matri_id_by, str_gender;
String str;

//Imageloader to load image
private ImageLoader imageLoader;
private Context context;

//List to store all superheroes
List<SuperHero> superHeroes;

//Constructor of this class
public CardAdapter(List<SuperHero> superHeroes, Context context){
    super();
    //Getting all superheroes
    this.superHeroes = superHeroes;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.superheroes_list, parent, false);
    // Session class instance
    session = new SessionManager(context);
    session.checkLogin();
    // get user data from session
    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
    matri_id_by = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_EMAIL);
    str_gender = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_GENDER);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    //Getting the particular item from the list
    final SuperHero superHero =  superHeroes.get(position);

    //Loading image from url
    imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
    imageLoader.get(superHero.getImageUrl(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.imageView, R.drawable.image, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));

    holder.imageView.setImageUrl(superHero.getImageUrl(), imageLoader);
    holder.textViewId.setText(superHero.getMglId());
    holder.AgeHeight.setText(superHero.getAgeHeight()+" / "+superHero.getAge());
    holder.Community.setText(superHero.getCommunity()+" / "+superHero.getCaste());
    holder.Occupation.setText(superHero.getOccupation());
    holder.Income.setText(superHero.getIncome());
    //   holder.btnShortlist.setText(superHero.getShortlist());
    //   holder.btnEI.setText(superHero.getExpress_Intrest());

    holder.btnShortlist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            superHero.setShortlist("Wait...");
            holder.btnShortlist.setText(superHero.getShortlist());
            matri_id_to = superHero.getMglId();
            holder.shortlist(position);
        }
    });

    str = superHero.getShortlist();
    Log.e("sh____________",str);

    if(str.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("shortlisted")) {
        holder.btnShortlist.setText(str);
        holder.btnShortlist.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0E3671"));
        holder.btnShortlist.setEnabled(false);
    }
    else{
        holder.btnShortlist.setText(str);
    }


    holder.btnViewProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent n = new Intent(holder.itemView.getContext(),BlankActivity.class);
            String str_id = holder.textViewId.getText().toString();
            n.putExtra("ID",str_id);
            holder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(n);
        }
    });


    holder.btnEI.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        }
    });

}

public SuperHero getItem(int position){
    return superHeroes.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {return superHeroes.size();}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public NetworkImageView imageView;
    public TextView textViewId;
    public TextView AgeHeight;
    public TextView Community;
    public TextView Occupation;
    public TextView Income;
    public Button btnShortlist;
    public Button btnViewProfile;
    public Button btnEI;

    //Initializing Views
    public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewHero);
        textViewId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
        AgeHeight = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.AgeHeight);
        Community = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Community);
        Occupation = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Occupation);
        Income = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Income);
        btnShortlist = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnshort);
        btnViewProfile = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonViewProfile);
        btnEI = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnExpressIntrest);
    }

    public void shortlist(final int position) {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                if (response.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                    superHeroes.get(position).setShortlist("Shortlisted");
                    holder.btnShortlist.setText(superHero.getShortlist());
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put(KEY_MATRI_ID_BY, matri_id_by);
                params.put(KEY_MATRI_ID_TO, matri_id_to);
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
      }
     }
    }
```

Comment: you can set text of button on success response of that action.

Comment: Yes I did it as button.setText("Shortlisted") but it does not take it

Comment: On success of your api call, you're only calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` for the adapter having the old data-set. How are you updating the `List<SuperHero>` on success of api call? I think you're missing this part.

Comment: I used button.setText("Shortlisted") on Success but it's not working and I remove it from there

Comment: Since there's no changes being mage in your data-set, once you call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, it's gonna bind the old values to the views. Try returning list in api response, and subsequently, changing the older list to newer one and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: Please explain what do u want to tell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is in onClickListener. update the code as mentioned below:

```
holder.btnShortlist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            superHero.setShortlist("Wait...");
            holder.btnShortlist.setText(superHero.getShortlist());
            matri_id_to = superHero.getMglId();
            holder.shortlist(position);    
        }
     });
```

If you don't do so then your view will be reset when you scroll or the item will be recycled for the condition you have added:

```
if(str.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("shortlisted")) {
    holder.btnShortlist.setText(str);
    holder.btnShortlist.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0E3671"));
    holder.btnShortlist.setEnabled(false);
}
else{
    holder.btnShortlist.setText(str);
}
```

Further,

```
public void shortlist(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            if (response.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                // If response is success then button's text should be changed i.e "Shortlisted"     
                superHeroes.get(position).setShortlist("Shortlisted");
                holder.btnShortlist.setText(superHero.getShortlist());
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put(KEY_MATRI_ID_BY, matri_id_by);
            params.put(KEY_MATRI_ID_TO, matri_id_to);
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

If still it will not come then call notifyDataSetChanged() at the last of onClick().

Update you condition and get your required result:

If you change any UI in adapter in if block then there should be proper reflect of the same change in UI for else case otherwise when the view will refreshed, you UI may not recycled as per desired. So updated your code for the condition you have mentioned:

```
if (str.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("shortlisted")) {
        holder.btnShortlist.setText(str);
        holder.btnShortlist.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0E3671"));
        holder.btnShortlist.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        holder.btnShortlist.setText(str);

        //Color you want in else case
        holder.btnShortlist.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0E3671"));

        //State you want in else case
        holder.btnShortlist.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

Comment: Wait... is coming on button text now and I have checked with notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Please vote up and accept the answer if it is a solution to your question. Thanks

Comment: there is no solution yet my issue because when I am clicking on button then wait... is coming on button's text

Comment: superHero.setShortlist("Wait...") is working when clicking on button but if response is success then  btnShortlist.setText("Shortlisted"); not working

Comment: Updated my answer further.

Comment: There is no way for not to work the code. You can debug your code and can check the flow. May be you are missing something else somewhere. Otherwise if you are using the same code then it should work.

Comment: But it show error on     holder.btnShortlist.setText(superHero.getShortlist());

Comment: It does not take superHero here

Comment: my friend, take list varible.getShortlist.... As per the logical flow I can see, you can comment this line and it should work as you are calling notifyDataSetChanged() just after that. Please update the variable to your class variable (List variable) or comment the line and let me know if it is having problem further.

Comment: @VKSGODIYAL this is accepted answer. For your understanding, debug and follow al above mentioned steps.

Comment: Please can you tell me exact that where should I added button onClickListiner because in below answer he is saying that you have to move your onClickListener in your ViewHolder.

Comment: can not resolve symbol   holde and superHero in line   holder.btnShortlist.setText(superHero.getShortlist());

Comment: Your code to write onClickListener is correct. Can you please update your present code? I will check and then comment further.

Comment: When I have comment this line (holder.btnShortlist.setText(superHero.getShortlist());) then it's working but there is one another problem with  holder.btnShortlist.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0E3671"));      In some item's button color is different if text is shortlist

Comment: I have corrected your error at the end of the answer. Check and get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way of doing this will be to pass the reference on the view you want to change.

```
 holder.btnShortlist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        holder.btnShortlist.setText("Wait...");
        matri_id_to = superHero.getMglId();
        shortlist( holder.btnShortlist,position); // change this line

    }
});
```

And then in your response you can do this.

```
 public void shortlist(final Button button , final int position) { // Pass button as param
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            if(response.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                // If response is success then button's text should be changed i.e "Shortlisted"
               button.setText("ShortListed"); // finally set your text     
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put(KEY_MATRI_ID_BY,matri_id_by);
            params.put(KEY_MATRI_ID_TO,matri_id_to);
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

**EDIT:**

you have to move your `onClickListener` in your `ViewHolder`.

```
 public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    imageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewHero);
    textViewId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
    AgeHeight = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.AgeHeight);
    Community = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Community);
    Occupation = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Occupation);
    Income = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Income);
    btnShortlist = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnshort);
    btnShortlist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        btnShortlist.setText("Wait...");
        matri_id_to = superHeroes.get(getAdapterPosition()).getMglId();
        shortlist(btnShortlist,position); // change this line

    }
});

}
```

Comment: In this logic when I clicked on button then above item's button text is changed

Comment: I don't think this would work once the view is recycled.

Comment: you have to move your `onClickListener` in your `ViewHolder`. your `onClickListener` is reinitializing everytime it is created.

Comment: then I try this (shortlist(btnShortlist,getAdapterPosition());) and yet not working

Comment: @M.WaqasPervez please tell me this error I did not resolve yet

Comment: can you update your question with the code you are trying so i can get what you are doing